# Cannot sort by position in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sorting

I am trying to force a category of products to sort by position in Magento 1.9.2.4. I have assigned the position to each product in the category but I notice there is no position option - only by Best Value, Name, and Price (see image below).

Can anyone please advise a fix?

[image]

Comment: Position marked products not on 1st page, https://snipboard.io/qbu7W5.jpg any  help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Best Value` is the same thing as `Position` - I'm not certain on why they decided to call it two different things, but they are related.

Position is the numbering order you set where 0 is the "best value" and higher than that will come after.

So if you want products `A B C D` to show up in a specific order, you would order them `2 4 1 3` to rearrange them as `B D A C` - then select `best value` in the sorting options.

You can also set the option to `name` and they will sort alphabetically, or `price` and they will sort by lowest to highest price.

You can set this globally in the `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend` area

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? The answer I gave is correct.

Comment: I guess the dowvote was before your edits ;)

Comment: My previous answer was a bit too simple. Hopefully, the edit gives a better explanation.

Comment: Yes it does, but the example is not _sooo_ good - for alphabetic order you can sort by "Name" :P

Comment: Good point. I have updated them again to hopefully resolve this confusion.

Comment: Think it needs no examples ;) It's explained in 1st and 2nd line :)

Comment: @StevenJ Position marked products not on 1st page, https://snipboard.io/qbu7W5.jpg any  help thanks.

Comment: @Gem Are the other products left blank in this position field? In Magento's eyes, Blank = 0. Zero is greater than 1, so Magento puts those products ahead of any other ordering being done.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank you for this post and I wanted to add to it for the next step in setting the product's position.

Once you have gone through the steps above, then you will want to:

1. Navigate (in the CMS) to *Catalog> Manage Categories>*  and choose your store view.
2. Pick your product's category and navigate to it's folder.
3. Select that folder
4. In that category's folder, on the Tab-strip menu, select "Category Products"
5. On the far right hand side, underneath the Reset Filter and Search button you will find the "Position" column.
6. Here you can assign your product listing position for that category's product menu. Remember that in Magento 0 is first position, number 1 is second and so on.
7. Once your menu list order is assigned, "Save Category".
8. Reindex
9. Flush Cashe
10. Your product, it should be in the order you assigned it.

Cheers and Happy Magentoing!